# Find three infinite sets A, B, C such that A∆B∆C = {−1, 0, 3}.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have tried with Z numbers with three sets:

A={n∈Z | n≡0 mod3}
B={n∈Z | n≡1 mod3}
C={n∈Z ∣ n≡2 mod3}

AΔBΔC=(A∪B∪C)−(A∩B)−(B∩C)−(C∩A)+(A∩B∩C)

How could I continue to solve this problem, or am i taking the right approach to this kind of problem. I'm new to discrete mathematics.

Need a bit help if possible.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symmetric difference $A\operatorname{\triangle}B\operatorname{\triangle}C$ consists of all elements that belong to an odd number of the sets $A,B,C$.

So put each of the elements $-1,0,3$ into just one (or all three) of the sets $A,B,C$. That gets us $A\operatorname{\triangle}B\operatorname{\triangle}C=\{-1,0,3\}$. But we want the sets to be infinite, so we add more elements to them; in order not to change the symmetric difference, each additional element goes into an even number, namely two, of the three sets.

Put $4,7,10,13,\dots$ in $A$ and $B$.

Put $5,8,11,14,\dots$ in $A$ and $C$.

Put $6,9,12,15,\dots$ in $B$ and $C$.

Finally we have:
$$A=\{-1,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,\dots\}$$
$$B=\{0,4,6,7,9,10,12,13,15,\dots\}$$
$$C=\{3,5,6,8,9,11,12,45,15,\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

I take it that $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference. It's not obvious that it's associative, but it is.

If you were asked to find three infinite sets $A,B,C$ such that $A\cap B\cap C=\{-1,0,3\}$, hopefully you can see that you need to start by adding $-1,0,3$ to $A,B,C$.

Then you need to make the sets infinite without affecting the intersection. One way to do this is to split the other members of $\mathbb{Z}$ into three infinite sets. A good way to do this is with $0,1,2\pmod 3$, as you suggest, so $A=\{-1,0,3\}\cup \{n\in \mathbb{Z}:n\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \land n\notin\{-1,0,3\}\}$ etc.

It might help you to draw a three-set Venn diagram, shade in the region $A\cap B\cap C$ and see where $-1,0,3$ and the rest of our integers go, to see what we have done.

Then draw another three-set Venn diagram and shade in the region that represents $A\Delta B\Delta C$.

Can you see where $\{-1,0,3\}$ need to go? In what regions can you put infinitely many objects to make $A,B,C$ infinite without adding anything to the symmetric difference?